# How to match '+abc' but not '++abc' without lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex

In a sentence similar to:

> Lorem ipsum +dolor ++sit amet.

I'd like to match the `+dolor` but not the `++sit`. I can do it with a lookbehind but since `JavaScript` does not support it I'm struggling to build a pattern for it.

So far I've tried it with:

```
(?:\+(.+?))(?=[\s\.!\!]) - but it matches both words
(?:\+{1}(.+?))(?=[\s\.!\!]) - the same here - both words are matched
```

and to my surprise a pattern like:

```
(?=\s)(?:\+(.+?))(?=[\s\.!\!])
```

doesn't match anything. I thought I can trick it out and use the `\s` or later also the `^` before the `+` sign but it doesn't seem to work like that.

---

EDIT - background information:

It's not necessarily part of the question but sometimes it's good to know what is this all good for so to clarify some of your questions/comments a short explanation:

- any word in any order can by marked by either a `+` or a `++`
- each word and it's marking will be replaced by a `<span>` later
- cases like *lorem+ipsum* are concidered to be invalid because it would be like splitting a word *(ro+om)* or writing two words together as one word *(myroom)* so it has to be corrected anyway (the pattern can match this but it's not an error) it should however at least match the *normal* cases like in the example above
- I use a lookahead like `(?=[\s\.!\!])` so that I can match words in *any* language an not only `\w`'s characters

Comment: did you want to match `+bar` in `foo+bar` ?

Comment: No, it is a sentence and there won't be such cases. There will always be either a space `\s` or `^` before the `+`.

Comment: then why you accepted the answer which captures `+bar` in `foo+bar`?

Comment: Because a `foo+bar` would be a typo and needs to be corrected anyway. It would be the same as if I wrote _myroom_ instead of _my room_.

Comment: @AvinashRaj as you probably know it's not always easy or obvious which answer to accept like in this case. I picked @TimPietzcker's answer because although it isn't perfect (like you've said it matches too many cases) it explains the trick to match only one `+` before a word. After all I mixed his and @hsz's answer with my own pattern and solved it. We need another option like _partial answer_ ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to match one additional character and ignore that (by putting the relevant part of the match into a capturing group):

```
(?:^|[^+])(\+[^\s+.!]+)
```

However, this breaks down if potential matches could be directly adjacent to each other.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tD4yN3/2).

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # Match (but don't capture)
 ^          # the position at the start of the string
|           # or
 [^+]       # any character except +.
)           # End of group
(           # Match (and capture in group 1)
 \+         # a + character
 [^\s+.!]+  # one or more characters except [+.!] or whitespace.
)           # End of group
```

Comment: It's hard to pick an answer but I think this one lead me to the right direction and I'll go with a pattern like `(?:^|\s)(\+([^+\s]+))(?=[\s\.!\!])` which is kind of combination of both patterns. Matching the additional character at the beginning did the trick. I've added another group because I need to replace it later so it solves this particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
\+\+|(\+\S+)
```

Grab the content from capturing group 1. The regex uses the trick described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between/23589204#23589204).

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jA3bZ3/1)

```
var re = /\+\+|(\+\S+)/g;
var str = 'Lorem ipsum +dolor ++sit ame';
var m;
var o = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }

    if (m[1] != null) {
        o.push(m[1]);
    }

}
```

If you have input like `+++donor`, use:

```
\+\++|(\+\S+)
```

Comment: Whoever did that obviously doesn't know the difference between capturing and non-capturing matches... @t3chb0t I think you should rather accept this answer as it doesn't suffer from problems with adjacent matches like `+dolor+sit` (where mine would only find `+dolor`).

Comment: @TimPietzcker he has to replace those captured with something else.So urs might be better replacing in this will require more effort.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex seems to be working for me:

```
var re = / (\+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/  // Note the space after the '/'
```

Demo

https://www.regex101.com/r/uQ3wE7/1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you needed.

```
(?:^|\s)(\+[^+\s.!]*)(?=[\s.!])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
(^|\s)\+\w+
```

Comment: but this matches the preceding space also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I think it doesn't really matter - the text can be obtained with capturing group anyway.

Comment: but your regex matches `+dolor` in this `foo+dolor` string also.